# Sugar ORM overwrites ID from feed

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm writing an Android application that uses Sugar ORM for my data persistence. I have a case where I am getting an objectID from a web server, and this ID needs to be the same as my record's ID on the local database. That way my data record will be updated correctly when saved later on.

The issue I am having is that whenever I extend the SugarRecord class Sqlite is overwriting the ID I am setting in the object. For example, the ID in my feed is 2 but when inserted into the database the ID is changed to 1.

Is there anyways to prevent the auto incrementing that the database is doing with Sugar ORM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In sugar ORM primary key with autoincrement property is set with id column by default.Try to update the schema version by entering some higher number in Manifest file and also rename the variable(id variable in POJO class)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using a different name for the column, but wouldn't that mean that Sugar ORM wouldn't know how to determine to insert or update the record? If do that I'm pretty sure I'd have to manually manage the insert/update routine to ensure I don't get duplicate entires.

Comment: my question really is how do I circumvent the default behavior in Sugar ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that I solved by overwriting the ID setter in my model class like this :

```
public class MyClass extends SugarRecord {

    @Unique
    private Long id;

    // default constructor for SugarRecord
    public MyClass() {

    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        // Use "super" to overwrite
        super.setId(id);
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```